# Sharing files in C# on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a class file xxx.cs which I wish to share with 3 projects, each containing an executable.  I know I can create a class library which can be shared by all three executables but I do not wish to create an extra library, I just want 3 standalone executables.  Libraries in C# have weird copying problems on large projects.

[C# share code between classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878419/c-sharp-share-code-between-classes) says don't copy code between projects.  I'm not doing it but VS is.

If I add an existing file from another project to a project, VS takes a copy of that file into the local directory of the project so I now end up with 3 copies of the same file.  When I then make the changes to one of the copies, it is not reflected in the other two.  Again, VS doesn't do this in C++, only in C#.  I'm just wondering if there is a way of stopping VS from taking a copy locally.

The workaround is to modify the vsproj file using notepad and change the file reference to a relative link.  It then appears with a link symbol in VS.  Instead of editing vsproj files, is there a way of doing this from VS?